# Retrieve value from dynamic TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox

I have a `Button` that creates a list of `TextBoxes` Dynamically and I also have a `Button` that submits the information.  However I don't know how to access the values of the `Textboxes`. Below is the code:

> ```
>         if (IsPostBack)
>         {
>             ViewState["count"] = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["count"]) + 1;
>             int Count = int.Parse(string.Format("{0}", ViewState["count"]));
>             var lstTextBox = new List<TextBox>();
>             for (int i = 0; i < Counter; i++)
>             {
>                 TextBox txtbx = new TextBox();
>                 txtbx.ID = string.Format("txtbx{0}", i);
>                 // txtbx.AutoPostBack = true;
>                 lstTextBox.Add(txtbx);
>                 //txtbx.Text = "initial value";
>             }
>             Session["lstTextBox"] = lstTextBox;
>         }
> protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         int total = Counter;
>         for (int i = 0; i < total; i++)//Calls to createbox
>             CreateTextBox(i);
>         //Label1.Text = Counter.ToString();
>         if (Counter == 4)
>         {
>             Button1.Visible = false;
>         }
>     }
>  private int Counter
>     {
>         get { return Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["count"] ?? "0"); } //Fields button counter
>         set { ViewState["count"] = value; }
>     }
> private void CreateTextBox(int j) //Creates the fields / cells
>     {      
>             var box = new TextBox();
>             box.ID = "Textbox" + j;
>             box.Text = "Textbox" + j;
>             var c = new TableCell();
>             c.Controls.Add(box);
>             r.Cells.Add(c);
>             table1.Rows.Add(r);
>     }
> ```

How would like to have `Button2` grab the values.

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: I'd personally use javascript to add a new text field rather than use lots of post backs.. then I'd just iterate through all the controls when the user presses submit.

Comment: Why are you storing the textboxes in `Session` cache and then not using that to actually build them?

Comment: I'd point out that you might want to change `if (Counter == 4)` to `if (Counter >= 4)` for safety.

Answer (score 0):

do it like this

```
 foreach(Control c in YourControlHolder.Controls)
 {
  if(c is TextBox)
   {
       //your code here.
   }
 }
```